# Is it possible to use the MySQL's ORDER BY FIELD() clause as part of the pre_get_posts hook?

Tags: plugin-development, wp-query

I'm just curious if it is possible to use the ORDER BY FIELD() clause using the `$query` via `pre_get_posts`, or if I need to use a Custom Query for that.

Here is the code I've tested but it didn't work:

```php
$query->set( 'orderby', 'FIELD(ID,5,3,4,1)' );
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `$query` here is a `WP_Query` object so it would make no difference if you did this via the `pre_get_posts` hook or by `new `WP_Query`, the end result before it generates SQL is identical. What are you trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: Multiple orderby is possible using default WordPress query parameters and it works in `pre_get_posts` hook too. Have a look at this make post.. https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/